# Get models within a calculated difference of days

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `Condition` which has a column called `expires_at` which stores a datetime.

Basically I need to get all Conditions that are about to expire. A Condition is about to expire when there are only 5 days left to reach the stored date.

How can I achieve this with Eloquent? I need to place the logic where the `where` is.

```
Condition::where(xxx)->get()
```

PS. I am using Carbon in case this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will return objects where `expires_at` is between now and +5 days from now moment.

```
Condition::whereBetween('expires_at', [Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addDays(5)])->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use scope;

you should add method in Condition class .

`public function scoperExpired($query) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 day'));
    return $query->where('expires_at', '<=', $date);}`

and now you can use expired as scope:-

`Condition::expired()->get()` 
will return all expired conditions.